# Likelihood Ratio Test without Chi-square test

Tags: estimation, maximum-likelihood, likelihood, likelihood-ratio

Likelihood ratio test (LRT) usually uses a chi-square test to compare two different models.

Are there any variants of LRT that does not use chi-square test?

Comment: The chi-squared test is asymptotic. While there are several asymptotic tests involving a chi-squared or normal approximation, you can sometimes compute a small sample distribution for the test statistic (or, even, simulate it to any desired degree of accuracy)

Comment: @Glen_b May I ask how can do that exactly? Any guide I can follow?

Comment: You're going to have to be more specific about what you want. Do what exactly?  An example of an exact distribution for a small sample statistic is [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Likelihood-ratio_test#An_example); i.e. in that specific instance, the likelihood ratio statistic is a monotonic function of a t-statistic, so the LRT would have exactly the same p-value as using a one-tailed t-test; you could even back out critical values for the LRT statistic itself from that. Mathematical statistics texts may have other examples and a few more are in questions on site ...

Comment: ... (e.g. its possible to derive an exact two-sample F-test for a one-tailed test of equality of exponential parameters). Note also that Wilks' asymptotic chi-square result imposes conditions that are not always satisfied (e.g. consider a test for a Uniform$(0,\theta)$ -- yet a small sample test can be derived there). Cases with simple sufficient statistics like that one are not typically the case, however. It would be best if you explained how this question arises - the particular context, and why you can't use an asymptotic chi-squared test.

Comment: Or did you mean ... ' how do I simulate it?'

Comment: I mean if I can use other tests instead of the chi-square likelihood test. In my knowledges AIC and BIC does not involves chi-square but they are also not "tests"

Comment: Naturally you can do small sample tests instead of using the Wilk asymptotic result, or any other asymptotic result (as I indicated in my initial response). All you need to be able to do is compute or approximate the distribution of the test statistic under the null (as you must do with any test statistic). As I indicate above this can sometimes be done algebraically, but otherwise could be done by simulation. I can't *give* a general algebraic derivation for every case, they're all different in small samples -- hence the discussion above of some specific examples.

Comment: I believe it would be possible to offer a useful answer to this question  but I remain unclear about *quite* what you need. A general step-by-step procedure is necessarily very vague - "compute or approximate the small-sample null distribution of $\Lambda=\mathcal{L}_0/\mathcal{L}_1$ (or some convenient monotonic transform of it, like $\log \Lambda$) and reject for sufficiently small values of $\Lambda$". Being much more specific about exactly how to do that depends on details which are still not present. (a variety of techniques may be employed).